# I have a score with a no value

Tags: javascript, split, local-storage

I'm creating a quiz and I use local storage to show the user their previous attempts. And I have a problem. When you take the quiz one time, at the end it shows "Score 0:" and then "Score 1: *actual score*". I'm not sure where that score 0 came from. If anyone could help me, it would be much appreciated.

```
document.querySelector(".check").onclick = function () {
        /* Hide unneeded sections and showing scores */
        quiz.classList.add("hidden");
        correctAnswer.classList.remove("hidden");

        /*Showing all previous scores */
        const lastScore = localStorage.getItem("latestScore") || "";

        const scoreDetail = lastScore.split(',');

        scoreDetail.push(score);

        localStorage.setItem("latestScore", scoreDetail);

        let userScoreTemplate = `<h2>This Round's Score: ${score}</h2>`;

        scoreDetail.map((items, index) => {
            userScoreTemplate += `<h3>Score ${index}: ${items}</h3>`;
        });

        let userScoreBoard = document.querySelector(".user-score");

        userScoreBoard.innerHTML = userScoreTemplate;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

`${index}` will be equal to 0 initially as Arrays always begin at index 0.

The fix:

```
scoreDetail.map((items, index) => {
    index++; //increase index by 1;
    userScoreTemplate += `<h3>Score ${index}: ${items}</h3>`;
});
```

*Explanation TL;DR:
Most programming languages use a zero-based index as an Array is a pointer and the index relates to the pointer's memory location. So the first memory location would be 0, and the second slot would be 1.*

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I just had to do this:

```
scoreDetail.map((items, index) => {
            userScoreTemplate += `<h3>Score ${index}: ${items}</h3>`;
            if (items==""){
                userScoreTemplate="";
            };
        });
```

Comment: Then what was your question? You asked "where from Score 0 came", there is already an answer solving & explaining that, your code here will still print the beginning index `0`.